# Is Chromium-42 compatible with react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am not sure if react-bootstrap is supporting Chromium-42. I know react-bootstrap is rewritten especially   for react, but what about browser support?

If i have a look at [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/browsers-devices/#supported-browsers), it is not supporting Chromium-42. My other question would be, is it possible to use Bootstrap 3 in react, so I dont have any browser support problems?

Comment: Download it and find out?

Comment: It certainly is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 is supporting Chromium-42.